Name for argument of type [long] not specified, Ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag - Spring Boot
I have this method to remove data:
public ResponseEntity<ReplyModel> remove(long code) {
        ar.deleteById(code);
        rm.setMensagem("The product has been removed!");
        return new ResponseEntity<ReplyModel>(rm, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

@DeleteMapping("/remove/{code}")
public ResponseEntity<ReplyModel> remove(@PathVariable long code) {
        return as.remove(code);
    }

But i'm getting this error wen im try to remove localhost:8080/remove/6:
"message": "Name for argument of type [long] not specified, and parameter name information not available via reflection. Ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag.", "path": "/remove/6".
I try to add @PathVariable but not working

@PathVariable was a move in the right direction, but I think you have to give it the expected name, like remove(@PathVariable("code") long code). The error message actually points to a missing name. Alternatively, you can define the name of the path variable in the method annotation, like @DeleteMapping(value = "code") without specifying the name in @PathVariable.

Starting with version 6.1, Spring no longer uses local variable table to retrieve parameter names. And because your Java compiler doesn't store method parameter names directly in the bytecode, Spring can't use reflection to map the value it receives in a request to a parameter of the method that should handle that request. To solve this problem, you can enable storing parameter names in bytecode using the -parameters compiler option. Or you can explicitly specify the name of the parameter to match in the annotation: @PathVariable("code")
For more information, see Upgrading to Spring Framework 6.x.
